# jQuery code won't work with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My jQuery code won't work with Bootstrap. As soon as I take out the link to the bootstrap.css, the jQuery works. I'm really not that familiar with Bootstrap, but I have to use it for a project. How do I get my simple jQuery to work with Bootstrap?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">    
<link href="holidaybaking3.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div id="snowflakeContainer">
    <p class="snowflake">*</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <header class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <img src="header2.png" style="width:100%">
        </header>
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->


 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="holidaybaking4.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="cookies2.html">Gingerbread Men</a></li>
      <li><a href="photos2.html">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="resources2.html">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



<article>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

<h1>Gingerbread Men</h1>

<div id="gingerbreadmeningredients" style="display: none;">

<img src="gingerbreadmenlist.png">
<br>

<button id="close">Close</button>

</div>


<div id="leftside" style="padding-top:20px">

<img class="hidden" src="step1.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step2.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step3.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step4.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step5.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step6.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step7.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step8.png">
<img class="hidden" src="step9.png">

</div>

<div id="rightside">

 <button id="next">Next</a>
 <button id="prev">Back</a>

</div>

<p id="ingredients">Click here for the ingredients</p>

</article>

<script src="fallingsnow_v6.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.js"></script>



<script>
$(function(){
                $("#gingerbreadmeningredients").hide();

                $("#ingredients").click(function(){
                    $("#gingerbreadmeningredients").fadeIn();
                    });

                $("#close").click(function(){
                    $("#gingerbreadmeningredients").fadeOut();
                    });


                $("#next").click(function(){
                        if ($("#leftside img:visible").next().length != 0)
                            $("#leftside img:visible").next().fadeIn().prev().hide();
                            else {
                                $("#leftside img:visible").hide();
                                $("#leftside img:first").fadeIn();
                            }
                            return false;
                            });

                    $("#prev").click(function(){
                        if ($("#leftside img:visible").prev().length != 0)
                            $("#leftside img:visible").prev().fadeIn().next().hide();
                            else {
                                $("#leftside img:visible").hide();
                                $("#leftside img:last").fadeIn();
                            }
                            return false;
                            });
                        });
</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you tried including the Jquery in the head instead of the body?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the link in your html to jquery that you are using jquery 3.  If I am wrong then let me know.  Bootstrap requires jquery version 1.9 or higher and lower than jquery 3.  So try using a version of jquery between 1.9 and 3 and I think it should work.

try and replace

```
<script src="jquery-3.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and see if that works.